# Пропсы поступают со второго клика/ Помогите понять проблему. Т.к. сам я её не вижу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Action creator

```
import {CREATE} from '../constants'
export function create() {
    return {
        type: CREATE,
        payload: {
            id: 1,
            data: [123]
        }
    }
}
```

REDUCER

```
import {CREATE} from '../constants'

export default (state ={}, action) => {
    const {type} = action
    switch  (type) {
        case (CREATE):
            return {action}
    }
    return action
}
```

ROOT REDUCER

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import creator from './creator'

export default combineReducers({
    creator
})
```

STORE

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducer from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

window.store = store;

export default store
```

COMPONENT

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {create} from '../AC'


class Creator extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    testReducer = () => {
        const {create} = this.props
        create();
        console.log(this.props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.testReducer}>TEST</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default connect(state =>({
    creator: state.creator
}), {create})(Creator)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Кажется не хватает mapDispatchToProps? Залили бы на https://codesandbox.io/, а то так непонятно

Comment: Да и reducer должен возвращать новый экземпляр state в случае изменений или state  из аргументов, если ничего не поменялось

Comment: Насчёт mapDispatchToProps я видимо ошибся, а с редьюсером беда

Comment: Я потом возвращал новый стейт, все равно при первом клике ничего не происходит. 
Данное явление происходит если это все делать в одном методе. Но если проверить пропсы в render-методе компонента то все в порядке. Если REDUX синхронный то почему нельзя в одном и том же методе компонента  вызвать метод из стора и сразу же проверить редаксовые пропсы? Из-за этого приходится делать грязным рендер-метод

Comment: Пропсы поступают в компонент в процессе жизненого цикла, который запустится заного, если отдиспатченный экшн повлияет на пропсы данного компонента, если я правильно понял.. Собственно в том и есть вся соль реакта, что компоненты суть функция пропсов и иногда состоянить. И контекста

Comment: Теперь я вас понял. Редакс обновит пропсы компонента, что вызовет по кругу все функции начиная от componentWillReceiveProps и заканчивая componentDidUpdate (если по дороге ничего не случится). Поэтому нельзя ожидать что this.props будут новым на следующей строчке. Собственно это и не нужно

Comment: Так как тогда читать информацию из редакса в одном методе на след.строке если это необходимо?

Comment: Теоретически это возможно, но практически я не знаю как. Но вопрос - а зачем? Если наши компоненты - функция от пропсов, тогда этот вопрос должен отпасть сам собой.. Сбросили бы может пример рабочего когда, где возникает проблема